# Overriding part of the __init__ method in a subclass in Python 2

Tags: python, class, subclass

I'm wanting to create a subclass of a subclass (Barrier is a type of wall, which is a type of obstacle), and I'm wanting the barrier to have the same **init** method as wall with the exception that the self.type = 'barrier', but I'm not sure how to do this (I'm very new to programming so I'm sorry if this is very simple but I haven't been able to find an answer I understand). So far I have:

```
class Obstacle:
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = 'obstacle'

    def __str__(self):
        return "obstacle"

class Wall(Obstacle):

    def __init__(self, origin, end):

        self.type = 'wall'
        self.origin = origin
        self.end = end

        # etc.... (i.e. there are more things included in here which the 
        # that the barrier also needs to have (like coordinate vectors etc.)

class Barrier(Wall):

    def __str__(self):
        return "Barrier obstacle"
```

How do I change it so that class Barrier has identical contents of the **init** method as Walls do, except their "self.type = 'barrier'"?

Answer (score 7):

Just override that one attribute after invoking the `Wall` version:

```
class Barrier(Wall):
    def __init__(self, origin, end):
        super().__init__(origin, end)
        self.type = 'barrier'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Barrier obstacle"
```

You may want to consider using class attributes instead however; none of your instance attributes are dynamic and specific to each instance of the class. The `type` attribute of each of these classes surely won't change from one instance to another:

```
class Obstacle:
    type = 'obstacle'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class Wall(Obstacle):
    type = 'wall'

    def __init__(self, origin, end):
        super().__init__()
        self.origin = origin
        self.end = end
        # etc.... (i.e. there are more things included in here which the 
        # that the barrier also needs to have (like coordinate vectors etc.)

class Barrier(Wall):
    type = 'barrier'
```

Comment: I just tried doing this, but I get errors when I try to create an instance of the class, as it says that the __init__ for Barrier only has one argument, but I also need to give the origin and end points?

Answer (score 2):

Since the "type" seems to depend on the class, I would simply not **put the `type` attribute in the object**, but at the **class level**:

```
class Obstacle:

    type = 'obstacle'

    def __init__(self):
        # do something
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return "obstacle"

class Wall(Obstacle):

    type = 'wall'

    def __init__(self, origin, end):
        super().__init__()
        self.origin = origin
        self.end = end

class Barrier(Wall):

    type = 'barrier'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Barrier obstacle"
```

Furthermore you better call the `super().__init__` method if you override it. Since otherwise initializations higher in the class hierarchy will not take place (this is sometimes desired behavior, but usually it is not).

The advantage of this is that it is - in my opinion at least - more elegant. Since here it is clear that `type` is defined per class. But furthermore it will reduce the amount of memory that is used. Since we store *one* attribute per class, *not* one per object.

However in case you want to alter the attribute of a single object, that is still possible. For instance:

```
>>> obs1 = Obstacle()
>>> weird_obs = Obstacle()
>>> weird_obs.type = 'weird obstacle'
>>> obs2 = Obstacle()
>>> obs1.type
'obstacle'
>>> weird_obs.type
'weird obstacle'
>>> obs2.type
'obstacle'
```

So we still have the flexibility to add a specific type to a specific object. But by default, if we query an obstacles `type`, it will perform a fallback and return the `type` that is defined on the class level.

Comment: Just in case the OP doesn't understand: The difference here between using `self.type = 'barrier'` in `__init__` and `type = 'barrier'` under the class dentition, is that the latter creates a "static" variable. That basically means that the `type` attribute will be shared across all instances of `Barrier`. The benefit here is that since `type = 'barrier'` never changes per instance, you can have all instance share the one attribute rather than letting each instance have it's own attribute.